# How can I add a notification to this code that informs the user when a new product is recalled from the link?

Tags: react-native, expo, mobile-application

Code wrote with react native and use expo go with iphone.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { View, Text, ScrollView, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import cheerio from 'cheerio';

const App = () => {
  const [recalledProducts, setRecalledProducts] = useState([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const scrollViewRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRecalledProducts();
  }, [currentPage]);

  const fetchRecalledProducts = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`https://www.gov.uk/product-safety-alerts-reports-recalls?page=${currentPage}`);
      const html = await response.text();
      const $ = cheerio.load(html);

      const products = [];

      $('.gem-c-document-list__item').each((index, element) => {
        const title = $(element).find('.gem-c-document-list__item-title').text().trim();
        const summary = $(element).find('.gem-c-document-list__item-description').text().trim();
        const date = $(element).find('.gem-c-document-list__item-metadata').text().trim();

        products.push({ title, summary, date });
      });

      setRecalledProducts(products);
      setIsLoading(false);

      scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({ y: 0, animated: true });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Hata:', error);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const handleNextPage = () => {
    setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
  };

  const handlePrevPage = () => {
    if (currentPage > 1) {
      setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
        ref={scrollViewRef}
        onScroll={(event) => {
          const { y } = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset;
          scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({ x: 0, y, animated: true });
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.headerText}>PRODUCT RECALLS</Text>
        </View>
        {isLoading ? (
          <View style={styles.loadingContainer}>
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#666666" />
            <Text style={styles.loadingText}>Loading</Text>
          </View>
        ) : (
          recalledProducts.map((product, index) => (
            <View key={index}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>{product.title}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.summary}>{product.summary}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.date}>{product.date}</Text>
              {index < recalledProducts.length - 1 && <View style={styles.divider} />}
            </View>
          ))
        )}
      </ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.pageContainer}>
        <View style={styles.pageBox}>
          <Text style={styles.pageText}>Page: {currentPage}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      {currentPage > 1 && (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.backButton} onPress={handlePrevPage}>
          <Text style={styles.backButtonText}>Back</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.nextButton} onPress={handleNextPage}>
        <Text style={styles.nextButtonText}>Next</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}; 
.......
```

The purpose of this code is a react native mobile application that displays the data extracted from the url link with the parse method to the user and has the ability to switch between pages. The feature I want to add is that when a new product is listed on the site, it appears in the application, but I want to notify the user with a notification, how can I do it?